# 2 textview in 1 Edittext Android studio

Tags: javascript, android, android-edittext

So.. I have an EditText and I want to give him 2 or 3 values. Like.. First time when you write in edittext to show or save the first value, second time to show or save the second value etc. Can you help me with an example?

Comment: I see you tagged javascript. Are you using something a framework like Cordova (If yes you should tag the framework) or did you meant to tag java?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I use only Android studio..

Comment: So you propably meant to tag java. java and javascript have similar name but are wildly different

Comment: Show us a snippet what you have written on this

Comment: your question is not clear can you be more specific ?

Comment: I edited to javascript.. sry for that.. so.. more specific.. 1 edit text, 2 textviews. When you write in edittext first time, 1 textview take what did you write there. When you write again, second textview take what did you write there second time, not first. I try to do that bcs I dont want to use 2 edit texts.

Comment: @GAdrian Opposite, if you use android studio without anything else you are using java.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example:

```
 public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     setContentView(R.layout.countries);

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
     AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
             findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
     textView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }

 private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
     "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
 };
```

}

[AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.